# HTML Unicode character in Thymeleaf

Tags: html, unicode, thymeleaf

I want to convert a `<title>` tag to use a Thymeleaf fragment parameter. I'm currently using a Unicode character ([U+2708, airplane](https://unicode-table.com/en/2708/)) in my title. I'm not sure how to get Thymeleaf to accept this, though.

**Working, non-Thymeleaf:**

```
<title>AppName &#x2708; Page Title</title>
```

**Result:** AppName ✈ Page Title

**Thymeleaf Attempt 1:**

```
<title th:text="AppName &#x2708; ${title}"></title>
```

**Result:** TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression

**Thymeleaf Attempts 2/3:**

```
<title th:text="${'AppName &#x2708; ' + title}"></title>
<title th:utext="${'AppName &#x2708; ' + title}"></title>
```

**Result:** AppName ? Page Title

How can/should I escape that hex code in the `th` attribute so that it will be appropriately displayed as a unicode character?

Comment: For the benefit of easily reproducing your problem: what needs to change in file `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/home.html` from repo `https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-gtvg` so that `mvn compile` exhibits the errors you have?

Comment: Both of your bottom examples work for me -- have you set "UTF-8" as the encoding for both the view resolver and template engine? `resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` and `viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` depending on how you've configured everything.